# Cannot open DBF with spaces in the path

Tags: c#

using the following works when there is no spaces in the directory names

for string file1 it will execute reader with string file2 it will create an exception? I need to access folders that will have spaces in their path for some of our clients.

```
file1 = "C:\\test1\\file.dbf";
file2 = "C:\\test 2\\file.dbf";

OdbcConnection Connection = new OdbcConnection();
Connection.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};Exclusive=No;SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + strFilename + ";";
Connection.Open();

OdbcCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
Command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM " + file1; //Command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM " + file2;
```

once executing 
    Connection.Open();
 it opens it correctly,

once we execute 
     OdbcDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

I get *{System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]File 'file2.dbf' does not exist.*

---

Answer since I don't have enough rep

Thanks for everyones contribution the solution to my problem. The solution required that I put the full path (that has a space in it) and make it literal string using the @ char. For some reason making it literal by putting quotations with escape characters ("\"") did not solve it.

In summary, I used @ in front of the path in the connection string and in the command string.

```
strFilename = S.ImportFolder + "\\" +"file"+ ".dbf";

OdbcConnection Connection = new OdbcConnection();
Connection.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};Exclusive=No;SourceType=DBF;SourceDB="+@strFilename+";";
Connection.Open();

OdbcCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
Command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM "+ @strFilename;

OdbcDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: It's probably fair to say that it didn't connect to the database, although it would be nice to know what the actual error message is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you already try to put the path into quotes?

```
Connection.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};Exclusive=No;SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=""" + strFilename + """;";
```

Comment: well used escape char instead   `code` Connection.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};Exclusive=No;SourceType=DBF;SourceDB= \" + strFilename + "\"";`code`

Comment: No it didn't work. Wonder if it can be the FoxPro Driver. I know that it has to do with the MS-DOS naming convention. I still get the System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]File 'file2.dbf' does not exist.

Comment: @Roman If you use the `@` at the beginning, quotes must be escaped with another quote (`""`). Mixing both will lead to an unexpected result (e.g. `"...SourceDB=\C:\test 2\file.dbf"`).